# connect to ip:port usb-Ethernet adapter on android

Tags: android

I have an HTC One and i root it. I connect usb-Ethernet adapter with OTG cable to my phone and set ip address on it (eth0 192.168.9.1/24).
Then i connect it to my laptop with ethernet cable and set ip address from that subnet on my laptop(192.168.9.2/24). I can ping from both side(phone --> laptop and laptop --> phone)
then i write an android program to listen to port (33333):

```
 private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
         static final int SocketServerPORT = 33333;
         int count = 0;
         @Override
         public void run() {
          try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT,50,deviceAddress);
              socket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
  }
}


private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";

     try {
         Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces =  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "+ inetAddress.getHostAddress()   + "\n";
                    try {
                         deviceAddress=inetAddress.getByName(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                        //  deviceAddrgroup=inetAddress.getAllByName(inetAddress.getHostAddress());

                    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

When i want to connect to that port with (telnet 192.168.9.1 33333) from my laptop to my phone, it is not possible and telnet wait until timeout.

**I start troubleshooting :**

1 - use telnet 192.168.9.1 33333 on Terminal Emulator on my phone and i can connect to that port.

2 - i connect my phone to laptop with Wifi and i can connect to port 33333 without problem.

3 - i want to capture packet on android eth0 with Tcpdump. I copy Tcpdump on system/bin and system/xbin. When i want to execute tcpdump on Terminal Emulator, i have permission dined error! (my phone is root, and i use "su" before run that command)

4 - i use netstat on Terminal Emulator it show protocol tcp6 (::ffff:192.168.9.1)
!!!!

**my question :**

1 - any body had this problem before that can not connect to port on Ethernet-usb adapter?

2 - because protocol on android is tcp6, is it possible that cause the problem?

3 - any body known what is the problem of tcpdump on phone with root permission?

Comment: About Question number 2 : http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm  ::ffff:x.x.x.x is ipv4 compatible on ipv6. Instead of create one tcp/ip stack for ipv4 and one tcp/ip stack for ipv6.android use tcp/ip stack v6 with that compatiblity.so it should not be cause of problem.

Comment: Any idea!!!!????

Comment: About Question 3 : i find a page about tcpdump on android. I did these steps 1-su   2-mount -o remount,rw /system  3-copy tcpdump on /system/bin  4- cd /system/bin  5- run tcpdump -vv -s 0 -w /sdcard/tcp.cap  after step 5 i had new error about PIE. I googling and find tcpdump version thst support pie. my problem about tcpdump solved.finally i captured tcp packet on usb-ethernet. I received request connection to port 33333 on usb-ethernet but android did not response to it and after time request timeout!

Comment: may you say how to set a fixed IP address for usb-lan adapter?I have same problem and I don't know how to discover my android phone ip address.I also connected usb-lan adapter to android phone(but not rooted) using a OTG connector and need to find its ip in a pee-to-peer connection with windows laptop.it's highly appreciated if you help me.